# php - edit values from file

Tags: php, html

I having trouble editing a value I've already displayed from a file.
I've gathered bits and pieces together which I don't completely understand but gives me the desired functionality.
Would really appreciate all the help possible.

I have a site that displays values after a match has been found:

Search for a "S1value1" in sample.yml and display what is after ":" (This all works fine)

**search.php**

```
$lines_array = file('sample.yml');
$search_string = "S1value1";

foreach($lines_array as $line) {
  if(strpos($line, $search_string) !== false) {
    list(, $new_str) = explode(":", $line);
    $new_str = trim($new_str);
    }
}
```

**display.php**

```
<form action="edit_value.php" method="POST">
  <td>S1value1:</td>
  <td>Value:<input type="text" name="input1" value=<?php echo "$new_str"; ?>><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></td>
</form>
```

But in display.php I want to be able to edit what's in the input textbox and save the file

(Have no idea how to do that)

**edit_value.php**

```
Have no idea what to do here :(
```

Here is a sample input file.  I'm using a .yml, cannot change that.

**sample.yml**

```
Service1:
   S1value1: one
   S1value2: two
Service2:
   S2value1: one
   S2value2: two
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have at the moment `' one'` as the value. you can use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with quite simple pattern.

```
$str = ' one';    
$str = preg_replace('/([ ]){1}([a-z]){3}/', ' two', $str);
```

on the pattern `([ ]){1}([a-z]){3}`

`([ ]){1}` means that its preceeded by one whitespace and `([a-z]){3}` three lowercase letters that are in alphabet between or are `a` to `z`.

after comma `' two'` is the actual replacement. it can be anything you want. and the third is the target what are we replacing.

PS: im not that good in regex please correct me if im wrong